# android studio app won't launch on emulator

Tags: android-studio

I'm very new to android studio and I tried running the default (blank) app that android studio creates with a simple textview. the emulator will launch, but not the app -- There are no errors

The first time I installed android studio, running apps could work quickly and without a problem, but now it doesn't seem to anymore

Comment: AS launches emulator first, then run app when emulator become online. If it takes more than 300 sec, APK installation will aborted. When this happens, you just need to run again or launch emulator first before executing the app.

Comment: @FrozenFire I have tried both waiting and launching the emulator first, but that doesn't work either

Comment: Did the emulator started correctly?

Comment: it starts correctly

Comment: Try disabling instant run. `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run`

Comment: Sometimes when we try to launch app, Android Studio failed to do that. In my case, it's failed about 1/5 times. It happens only when I upgrade to AS 2.1, never happened with AS 1.5.
As @FrozenFire comments, try disabling Instant Run.

Comment: @FrozenFire disabling instant run doesn't seem to work either. I will try using an actual device